# How to remove Path in the URL

Tags: java

How can I dynamically remove a path from a URL? For example I want to remove path1 in the example

URL: https://example.com/context/path1/path2/path3

so it will become: https://example.com/context/path2/path3

It can be any path from the URL.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `java.nio.file.Path` class that have support for hierarchical operations. Like so:

```
    URI uri = URI.create("https://example.com/context/path1/path2/path3");

    Path path = Paths.get(uri.getPath());

    String componentToRemove = "path1";
    Path tmp = Paths.get("/");
    for (int i=0; i < path.getNameCount(); ++i) {
        String s = path.getName(i).toString();

        if (!componentToRemove.equals(s)) {
            tmp = tmp.resolve(s);
        }
    }
    URI result = new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), tmp.toString(), null);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: This won't work on Windows without adding `.replace(File.separator, "/")`.

Comment: @DuncG Ah, true! Windows!